# cakephp site within an iframe

Tags: cakephp, iframe, cakephp-2.3

I have developed a site using cakephp 2.x.

I want to show cakephp site in another site using iframe.
When I use Iframe code in normal site, Iframe displaying blank content with provided styles.

Below is the Iframe code

```
<iframe 
    src='http://mycakephpsite.com/' 
    width='600' height='800' 
    frameborder='1' 
    scrolling='yes' 
    align='bottom' 
    style='border:1px #68293c dotted;'>
</iframe>
```

Please let me know where I am doing mistake.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This iframe works for me:

```
<iframe 
sandbox="allow-scripts allow-forms allow-same-origin" 
src="http://www.mycakephpsite.com/">
</iframe>
```

I think you may have an issue with your web server headers, check your X-Frame-Options option

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options